# Visitors have old website cached in their browsers

Tags: browsers, cache, google-chrome

My client's new website is example.com, the old website is  example.co.uk. I've re-pointed the A Records to the new website (so as to leave the emails alone) and put in 301 redirects from old pages to new pages.

But, my client is upset as he (and he thinks many of his clients) have the old website cached in their browsers and won't know how to clear their browser cache.

Is there anything I can do to overcome this and if not, what sort of time will browsers finally stop using their cached pages so I can at least go back to my client and tell him that his clients will finally start to see the new website?

Comment: It's unlikely that a browser uses the cached version when the A record changed or the site issued a 301 redirect. My assumption is your client still gets the old A record. This "problem" will go away very soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the older site was instructing browsers and proxies to cache the site, that, more or less, is the time that everybody will have the old site in their cache.

One thing you can do, is check the site from a computer that has visited the old site. but is outside your clients network, that way, if they have any kind of proxy, you can show that a normal user is getting the new site already. If your client doesn't have any proxy in place, then go back to the first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's most appreciated.I can't see any cache instructions in the old website and no .htaccess file. Am I correct in thinking that all of my clients browsers will eventually go to the new website anyway?

Comment: yes, eventually, they all will go because the old one is going to disappear, either because you remove the content or because you redirect the whole site to the new one. About the cache instructions, even if you didn't set anything in the .htaccess, the server is sending http headers with every object, plus the server side language used to build the site may also be sending http headers. I recommend that you install live http headers in firefox and check the site with that enabled, the you can see how long is going to take for the cache to expire. Or you can post it here and we will tell you.